# vim >> rotate through all buffers opened in target split

Tags: vim, split, rotation, buffer, hidden

Am used to IDE style tab'd panels and am hitting some arggghh inducing scenarios with vim when trying to replicate this functionality using buffers and splits.

I have the following relevant .vimrc settings:

```
set hidden
set switchbuf=useopen,usetab
```

Now, let's say I open up 4 buffers, split vertically and then horizontally so that 1 buffer displays on the left and 2 buffers display stacked on the right. The 4th buffer is hidden (opened on the left split).

With the cursor in the left split, using :bnext and :bprevious rotates through *all* buffers in the left split; that's not desirable as I really have no use for seeing the same file contents in 2 different splits (is there a way to opt-in to the vim cloned buffer affect?). Using :sbnext and :sbprevious works great for *visible* buffers, but as soon as a hidden buffer is encountered then it opens up in a new split thus wreaking havoc on my layout. The problem gets worse when working with 10+ buffers.

Ideally I'd like to rotate through all buffers visible and hidden within a given split (i.e. *where the buffers were opened*).

Suggestions appreciated.

p.s. am trying out vim ctrl-space plugin now, quite good but does not address above issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic navigation unit is the buffer. Windows and tab pages are abstractions built *on top* of buffers that introduce their own good and bad idiosyncrasies and, most of the time, don't play well with traditional buffers.

You are having troubles because you are trying to apply buffer commands to a window-centered workflow.

As soon as you split your workspace in more than one window you are bound to use window commands for navigation and tab-navigation becomes your standard as soon as you use tab pages. As you noticed, not only is it hard (impossible, AFAIK) to make buffer-navigation window/tab-aware but the alternative techniques actually lack quite a bit in terms of power.

> The 4th buffer is hidden (opened on the left split).

That's your first problem: that 4th buffer is hidden and thus transient. It is not opened in any window and could be displayed in any window. You can choose to display a specific buffer in a specific window but you can't really "pin" it to that window.

> With the cursor in the left split, using :bnext and :bprevious rotates through all buffers in the left split; that's not desirable as I really have no use for seeing the same file contents in 2 different splits (is there a way to opt-in to the vim cloned buffer affect?).

Again, you are using buffer commands that don't care at all about windows and tab pages.

> Using :sbnext and :sbprevious works great for visible buffers, but as soon as a hidden buffer is encountered then it opens up in a new split thus wreaking havoc on my layout.

Again, the wrong tool for the job.

It is possible to keep as many window-local argument lists as you have windows and use those lists with `:next` and `:previous`, though, but that would require quite a bit of focus and forethinking. Maybe there's a plugin for that? Anyway:

1. Create your layout:

   ```
   :vs|sp
   ```
2. Go back to the large window on the left:

   ```
   <C-w>w
   ```
3. Put two files in the local argument list:

   ```
   :arglocal aaa.txt bbb.txt
   ```
4. Move to the next window, edit your local argument list and repeat:

   ```
   <C-w>w
   :arglocal ccc.txt ddd.txt
   <C-w>w
   :arglocal eee.txt fff.txt
   ```
5. You can now do `:next` and `:previous` to switch arguments or `<C-^>` to switch to the alternate file.

Note that, while you were able to "force" somehow your buffers to specific windows, you are now seriously limited in your ability to navigate around *and* you now have to deal with a multi-dimensional construction that's rather fragile and requires to too many braincells.

You should consider working with Vim and not against it by using straight buffers as much as possible.

Answer (score 5):

Why rotate through the buffers when you can go directly to the one you want via `:buffer` command?

```
:b foo
```

`:b` take either a buffer number or a partial filename (with globs too!). I recommend the partial filename approach. You can also use tab completion to distinguish between ambiguous partial filenames.

You can use `:sbuffer` (`:sb` for short) the same way but to open a split instead.

For more help see:

```
:h :b
:h :sb
```

Comment: Sure, that works, kind of. Work with 20 tabs in an IDE, *all are visible*, so no context switching to the grey matter to query what the name of the file is that you need to edit, you just know its location in panel X's tab bar, or hotkey rotate through opened files (*where they were opened*). Must be the vim way, juggling filenames, would much prefer to visually rotate through buffers, the contents of which represent what a file is (not what it's called).

Comment: I see you point but I work with many buffers open  (100+ at times). Using tabs would simply not work for me. Instead I use `:b`, ctags/cscope, [projectionist](https://github.com/tpope/vim-projectionist), capital letter marks, `:vimgrep`/`:grep`/`:Ggrep`/`:Ack'`, and `<c-6>`. I would also wager that rotating through 20 tabs is rather inconvenient. Since you are looking for files by their contents I would suggest ctags/cscope and `:vimgrep` as good places to start. However if you are bound and determined to rotate through buffers then I suggest you map `:bn` and `:bp` to something convenient

Comment: I have already mapped :bn, :bp, the missing ingredient is predictability. Unfortunately splits give the illusion of IDE style tab'd layouts while delivering something else entirely. Editing is vim's strength, WM certainly is not.

Comment: Using a more buffer-centric workflow can be quite mind bending experience to those that come from a GUI window/tab-centric workflow. Vim is simply different and therefore the workflows will be different. I would suggest you try a buffer centric workflow for a few days. Try and only use 2 splits and forget about using vim's tabs. Use `:b`, ctags, `<c-o>`, `<c-6>`, capital marks, `:ls`, `:vimgrep`, and maybe some fuzzy finder like CtrlP. Forget about windows and tabs of other editors. Keep your layout simple, as you can only keep so many things in your head at once. Remember Vim is different

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [vim dwm plugin](https://github.com/spolu/dwm.vim), and it is working very well for my workflow. I'm used to open a lot of buffers in the same window. With this plugin I can manage all of them with easy. I'm using [vim-ctrlspace plugin](https://github.com/szw/vim-ctrlspace) too, and this two plugins are wonderful working together. Well, that's it. I hope this help!

Comment: agreed, vim ctrlspace is fantastic ;-)